# JSFiddle does not work on local machine

Tags: javascript

Could someone please help?  I found this code on JSFiddle, and copy and pasted it to a html file on my local machine.  It is suppose to be able to resize table cells.  This code works on JSFiddle but doesn't work on local machine.

The link to the JSFiddle page is: https://jsfiddle.net/18k3umpp/3/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Home</title>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

    html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    table {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90%;
    }

    table td {
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #views-container {
      height: 10%;
    }

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

/**
 * Created by yako on 1/25/16.
 */
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

console.log(inputs);
console.log(tds);
var changeView = function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (!inputs[i].checked) {
      if (tds[i].style.display !== 'none') tds[i].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      if (tds[i].style.display === 'none') tds[i].style.display = '';
    }
  }

  if (!inputs[0].checked && !inputs[1].checked) rows[0].style.display = 'none';
  else rows[0].style.display = '';

  if (!inputs[2].checked) rows[1].style.display = 'none';
  else rows[1].style.display = '';

};

changeView();



$(window).on("load resize", function() {

  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var v1Width = $("#v1").width()


  $("#v1").resizable({
    minWidth: 50,
    maxWidth: windowWidth - 80,
    maxHeight: windowHeight * (.83),
    handles: "e, s"
  }).on("resize", function() {

    if (v1Width == $("#v1").width()) {
      $("#v2").height(0)
    }
    v1Width = $("#v1").width()
  });

  $("#v2").resizable({
    maxHeight: windowHeight * (.83),
    handles: "s"
  }).on("resize", function() {
    $("#v1").height(0)
  });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>




 <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="v1">View 1</td>

      <td id="v2">View 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">View 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="views-container">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="changeView()">
    <label>View 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="changeView()">
    <label>View 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="changeView()">
    <label>View 3</label>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might be an stupid question to ask but have you downloaded the jQuery UI styles and scripts to the same folder as your html? If so, are you serving the html from file://? In that case, make sure to use a local web server as file urls are blocked from loading certain other resources.

Comment: the solution that i was directed to, because this was marked as a duplicate did not work for me.

Comment: yes i did, and I can not upload it to a server yet.  Im doing this for my job and they would just like it locally for now

Comment: You could try running a simple [local web server](https://gist.github.com/jgravois/5e73b56fa7756fd00b89). Have you checked the console to see if there is any error logged there? It is also possible you are missing the main jQuery library (I believe jQuery UI needs the main library). In that case you should get an error like 'jQuery is not defined' in the console.